# Adding regression to multiple series imported from CSV

Tags: highcharts

I have a multi-series Highcharts chart working fine when it just grabs data from a CSV file I create. I am trying to add a (loess) regression curve to it with the highcharts-regression plugin, but simply enabling the default regression results in the chart not showing up at all.  The application is at http://bmcnoldy.rsmas.miami.edu/vk/

First, the proper JS file for the plugin is called in my HTML: https://rawgithub.com/phpepe/highcharts-regression/master/highcharts-regression.js

None of the examples for highcharts-regression use multiple series that were imported from the built-in CSV import.

The guts of the chart-making (if regression:false then the chart works and shows up, if regression:true it breaks):

```
$.get('chart.csv', function(csv) {
   $('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
      csv: csv
    },
    series: [{
      (basic series options that work),
      regression: true,
    },{
      (basic series options that work),
      regression: true,
    },{
    ...
    }]
  });
});
```

Here's a snippet of my five-series CSV file for reference:

```
Date,Record High,Average High,Daily Average,Average Low,Record Low
"01-Jan-2000",80.2000,75.0000,72.0000,68.2000,45.5000
"02-Jan-2000",79.7000,75.0000,72.1000,68.3000,49.1000
"03-Jan-2000",79.2000,73.7000,70.0000,65.6000,46.4000
"04-Jan-2000",79.0000,72.0000,67.8000,63.7000,43.7000
"05-Jan-2000",80.2000,71.8000,67.4000,62.5000,44.2000
"06-Jan-2000",78.3000,73.0000,68.7000,63.5000,41.0000
"07-Jan-2000",78.3000,71.9000,67.5000,62.3000,45.5000
```

Inside of each series config, I tried adding
    `data: [],`
just so the data object was present... it didn't matter. But, is there a way to set data to be the proper columns in the csv object like 
    `data: [[csv[0]],[csv[1]]],`
or something like that?  Would that matter?

I just wanted to add a Loess regression curve to each of the five series, which looked so straightforward from the examples at https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression!

Thanks!

Comment: Here an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/y2584z0q/) with just `regression:true` and the second series with settings. Both works fine.

Comment: Yes, those work, but they have the "data" object within each series.  If I set regression:true, and leave everything else the same, the chart doesn't even get drawn.  My "data" object is set in the CSV import where all of the series are read in at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please notice that `linearRegression` indicator serves for finding single values (points, not lines) for the given period.

This **demo** illustrates how to get the regression line in Highchstock (it’s gonna work with data passed as `data.csv` too (although I didn’t do it to keep the clarity)): http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w0ohb647/

Highstock offers three indicators that will help us to find the line: `linearRegressionSlope`, `linearRegressionIntercept` and `linearRegressionAngle`. If we set their `params.period` to be the same as the data length then each of these indicator series will have **only one point**. It turns out that we can use y values of these points (slope, angle, intercept) to find the equation of the straight line we need: `y = slope * x + intercept`.

```
    this.addSeries({
      type: 'linearRegressionSlope',
      linkedTo: 'recordHigh'
    }, false);

    this.addSeries({
      type: 'linearRegressionIntercept',
      linkedTo: 'recordHigh'
    }, false);

    this.addSeries({
      type: 'linearRegressionAngle',
      linkedTo: 'recordHigh'
    }, false);
```

Highstock doesn’t offer any structures for representing infinite straight lines so we have to mimic it as a line segment:

`data: [regressionLineStart, regressionLineEnd]`

The parameter that you might find strange is `interceptOffset`. It has to be implemented because the place where our regression line crosses the mathematical y axis (y = 0) happens in 1st Jan 1970 (timestamp = 0) and we have to “pretend” that the mathematical y axis starts at `y = Date.UTC(2018)` (for purposes of my workaround).

Notice that auxiliary series (`linearRegressionSlope`, `linearRegressionIntercept` & `linearRegressionAngle`) don't ever appear thanks to setting `redraw` argument to `false` in `addSeries` and `remove` methods.

Comment: Thank you for bringing up this alternative way of adding a linear regression, and the addSeries concept (I may end up using that for something else!). I was hoping to get the highcharts_regression module working because I wanted to implement the Loess regression fitting it conveniently provides.  But before even playing with the options, I wanted to get the default working.

Comment: highcharts_regression is a module created by community (thus it's not guaranteed that it will work for all standard scenarios (such as importing CSV data)). Have you considered parsing your CSV manually and using it in `series[i].data` instead?